# Firebase AuthResult cannot resolve 'Task does not have type Parameters' and 'task.isSuccessful'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I keep getting 'cannot resolve' issues for certain Task parameters / methods and I think this is preventing me from implementing the abstract method, 'addOnCompleteListener'.

Currently it cannot resolve:

- Task < AuthResult >
- task.isSuccessful();
- task.getException();

Which I have shown in context below:

```
                    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(addressCheck, passwordCheck)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(SignInActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                    FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    // Go to maps
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",duration).show();
                                    // Remain on screen
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

I have seen the same question answered on here before but that solution points to dependencies within the app.build.gradle file which still didn't solve my problem. I'm currently using Firebase database (which works fine) and the auth UI which I am now trying to implement for Email and password sign in. Below are the current dependencies within my app.build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

I've had issues with them before which I resolved by:

- Updating the build tools
- Increasing the minimum target API
- Ensuring that the auth and database versions match
- Including the specific UI dependency for AuthUI
- Updating the emulators google play services (via the emulator itself)
- Including the latest Google play-services dependency too.

I have a feeling that, again, it will be related to this but as of now I'm currently stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have imported wrong `Task` class. Check your import statements.

Comment: That solved it! I checked it before and was convinced it was the right one - I guess not. Thanks you very much!